# LWC: JS based Integration or apex based rest integration, which is better and why?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, rest-api, apexrest

In **LWC**, what are the pros and cons of doing integration directly from JS (with help of methods such as *fetch*) when compared with normal apex based rest integration?

Please consider the situations of both simple and complex integrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither is strictly better when comparing all features.

Apex is better in terms of security (no authentication info needs to be sent to browser), and does not have to worry about CORS restrictions, but does have severe limits to ingress and egress bandwidth, callout timeout limits, and CPU limits. In addition, you cannot access resources not available to the public Internet.

In contrast, JS is better for larger integrations, as there is no inherent callout timeout limits, bandwidth, memory, or CPU limits, and you can access *intranet* resources, but you have to worry about getting authentication correct, as well as the fact that any "secrets" needed to access the resource must be exposed to the browser (thus, a savvy user could gain unexpected access to API resources).

When possible, Apex should be considered for integrations that are fine with the limits of Apex, as security is enhanced, but in practice, JS are better for most integrations.